# Add removed element back to DOM jQuery 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-2.0

I have the following code where I wanna remove and add an element back to the DOM in jQuery:

```
var pm_container = $(document).find('.pm-container');

$(document).on('change', '#payment-form .cat_field', function(){
    displayPrice($(this), pm_container);
});

function displayPrice(elem, pm_container){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getamount.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var amount_field = $(document).find('#payment-form #amount');

            amount_field.val(data.price);

            if(amount_field.val() == 0) {
                $(document).find('.pm-container').remove();
            } else {
                $(document).find('.save-listing').prev(pm_container);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For some reason, when the value of **amount_field** is not equal to zero, my element **.pm-container** is not added back into my page.

Any idea why?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use `detach` or show/hide instead of `remove`

Comment: replace `$(document).find('.pm-container').remove();` with this `pm_container = pm_container.detach();`

Comment: I suggest 2 changes; 1) Don't pass `pm_container` as an argument since it's a window variable. 2) Update the variable when you remove the element: `pm_container = $(document).find('.pm-container').remove();`

Comment: I cannot use hide/show because the elements are part of a form and I don't want the hidden fields to be submitted when I submit the form

Comment: I replaced remove by detach, but still I can't get the elements to re-appear on the page

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the element, it is gone. there is no way to get it back. one solution is to clone the element into a variable and be able to re-use it later:

> ```
> var pm_container = $(document).find('.pm-container').clone();
>
> $(document).on('change', '#payment-form .cat_field', function(){
> displayPrice($(this), pm_container); });
>
> function displayPrice(elem, pm_container){
> $.ajax({
>     type: 'GET',
>     url: 'getamount.php',
>     dataType: 'json',
>     cache: false,
>     success: function (data) {
>         var amount_field = $(document).find('#payment-form #amount');
>
>         amount_field.val(data.price);
>
>         if(amount_field.val() == 0) {
>             $(document).find('.pm-container').remove();
>         } else {
>             $(document).find('.save-listing').prepend(pm_container);
>         }
>     }
> }); }
> ```

However, for your case, Best way could be hiding and showing back the element:

> ```
> $(document).on('change', '#payment-form .cat_field', function(){
> displayPrice($(this)); });
>
> function displayPrice(elem){
> $.ajax({
>     type: 'GET',
>     url: 'getamount.php',
>     dataType: 'json',
>     cache: false,
>     success: function (data) {
>         var amount_field = $(document).find('#payment-form #amount');
>
>         amount_field.val(data.price);
>
>         if(amount_field.val() == 0) {
>             $(document).find('.pm-container').hide();
>         } else {
>             $(document).find('. pm-container').show();
>         }
>     }
> }); }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First create a variable for your Clone `.pm-container` outside ajax function

**Note*:** When you use .remove() you cannot take it back.

```
var container = $(".pm-container").clone();
```

then inside your ajax function

```
if (amount_field.val() == 0) {
  $(".pm-container").detach();
} else {
  container.insertBefore($(".save-listing"));
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/marksalvania/3h7eLgp1/

Comment: The elements are not inside the div with class **save-listing**. That's why I use **prev** and not prepend. I replaced remove by detach but still can't get the elements to re-appear on the page.